# Zooming of iframe contents with iframe itself?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, zooming, scale

I have this code for zooming contents of `iframe`

```
function SetZoom(){
var ZoomValue = 100;

try{
iframeDoc.body.style.zoom=ZoomValue+'%';
}catch(err){}
try{
iframe.body.style.OTransform = 'scale('+(ZoomValue/100)+')';
}catch(err){}

}
```

Now I need to imitate zooming of iframe
something like

```
iframe.style.width=(??????/ZoomValue)+'px';
iframe.style.height=(??????/ZoomValue)+'px';
```

Can't figure what should be instead of `???????`?

Answer (score 1):

** **edit** **
This should help you a lot better, just call `initZoom()` after the iframe has been added to the DOM.

```
var origWidth, origHeight;

// Call this once on page load
function initZoom(){
  // If you know the iframe's size is in pixels
  origWidth = parseFloat(iframe.style.width);
  origHeight = parseFloat(iframe.style.width);
}

// Call every time you change the zoom level
function zoom(size){
  iframe.style.width = (origWidth * size) + 'px';
  iframe.style.height = (origHeight * size) + 'px';
}
```

Thanks to `Basic` for the advice.

Comment: Problem is that I cannot restore it, and I need to zoom by any zoom value

Comment: Edited it but you have to figure out where to keep either the original dimensions or the last zoom.

Comment: If I were you, I'd store the original dimensions after page load - then you can just do calculations with the current zoom level and the original dimensions - no need to preserve previous state